# ¿Como puedo cargar un comboBox que esta anidado a otra tabla en JAVA (SQL)?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, combobox, crud

### Problema

Como puedo actualizar un dato de mi DB con un comboBox que esta anidado a otra tabla.
Es decir, para eso, yo cargo los datos en text fields, dataChoosers y el ComboBox anidado a otra tabla (para poder cambiar los datos y actualizar).
Entonces, los cargo, pero como puedo hacer que mi combo box agarre el dato de la tabla seleccionada?
Se que con el getSelectedRow puedo, y me sirve con todo, pero no me agarra los datos del comboBox debido a que esta anidad a otra tabla, no se si puedan ayudarme con este dilema, muchas gracias | :) & (: |

### Este el el metodo en mi Jframe

```
public void printLoad(){
        // Seleccionando la fila con el mouse (al hacer click sobre ella)
        int fila = listaPrestamo.getSelectedRow();
         // condicion para saber si la fila seleccionada si existe
         if(fila>=0){
             // estudiante, libro, fecha
             // obetengo el codigo de la fila seleccionada
             codigo.setText(listaPrestamo.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
             codigo.setEnabled(false);
             
             // intento cargar el comboBox con los datos de la fila seleccionada (datos que son anidados, 
             // se actualizan junto con otras tablas) pero el comboBox queda vacio
             estu.loadCombo(student);
             lib.loadCombo(book);
             // Intentos en vano tratando de cargar el comboBox
             // estudiante.setText(listaPrestamo.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
             // libro.setText(listaPrestamo.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString());
             
             // este bloque se puede omitir, sirve completamente
             SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
             Date guardarFecha;
             try{
                 guardarFecha = formato.parse(listaPrestamo.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString());
                 fecha.setDate(guardarFecha);
             }
             catch(Exception e){
                 Logger.getLogger(windowP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
             }
         }
    }
```

Aquí cargo los datos, pero solo me lee el código y el dataChooser, los comboBox nada

[image: Aquí cargo los datos, pero solo me lee el código y el dataChooser, los comboBox nada]

Les agradezco cualquier intento ._.